# Finding a mathematical pen pal

Tags: undergraduate-education

Is there a website where people can find a mathematical pen pal of sorts? It would be interesting to find someone with similar mathematical interests at a similar level to anonymously keep mathematically up to date with, so you could try to help each other learn, but I don't know any community where I can find someone like this easily.

Does such a place to find these people exist?

(Email would be the place for this to occur when I say pen-pal. Further, instant messaging doesn't seem appealing, asynchronous communication is strongly preferred)

[No idea how to tag this sorry]

Comment: I think paying attention to what goes on at MathStackExchange, and contributing what you can (either questions, answers, or comments), would likely lead to some connections beyond that site...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about teaching mathematics.